# How format give me error. not give me proper date

Tags: laravel

my parsing date format is in date/month/year (21/12/2020).

```
use carbon/Carbon

$date = Carbon::parse($request->date)->format('Y-m-d');
return $date;
```

Please help.

Comment: because its not valid date format.

Comment: have a view at the createFromFormat functon in the carbon class; https://carbon.nesbot.com/reference/#doc-method-Carbon-createFromFormat

Comment: 21/12/2020 this is d/m/Y, not Y-m-d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `createFromFormat` of `DateTime`. first of all, you need to convert this `string invalid date` format to `date format` by using `createFromFormat` 
 then you may format it in real date format.

```
$date='21/12/2020';   //dd/mm/yy
$new=DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date )->format('Y/m/d');
echo $new;
```

see [example](https://3v4l.org/PCbSp)

Edit:- 
By using carbon.

```
$date='21/12/2020';
$newdate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$date)->format('Y/m/d');
return $newdate;
```